# How to retrieve rows where the values of 2 columns are different in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

sql newbie here. I have a mysql table with rows like

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abra | ca | da | bra | sa | 7 |
| abra | fa | ll | of | mo | 8 |
| ac | st | da | bra | sa | 10 |
| ac | ca | da | bra | mo | 9 |
| pa | ni | rar | pat | sa | 11 |
| pa | pu | bra | sa | mo | 11 |

The values in column `e` are either `sa` or `mo`. For every value of column `a` there are always two rows one for `sa`, another for `mo` (plus several other rows).

I would like to get all rows that have the same column `a` value but the `sa` and `mo` rows have different values in their column `f`. So for the example above the query would filter out the last 2 rows since they both have value `11` in column `f` and would return

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abra | ca | da | bra | sa | 7 |
| abra | fa | ll | of | mo | 8 |
| ac | st | da | bra | sa | 10 |
| ac | ca | da | bra | mo | 9 |

I tried this query but it is not returning the right data

```
select * from table t1 where exists 
(select 1 from table t2 where t1.a <> '' 
and t2.a <> '' and t1.a=t2.a and (t2.e='sa' or t2.e='mo') and t1.e=t2.e and t1.f<>t2.f)  order by a
```

Comment: (sigh, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/OqgKhWWy  )   Error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table t1 where exists 
(select 1 from table t2 where t1.a <> '' 
and t2.a <> '' ' at line 2"

Comment: `t1.e=t2.e` seems wrong. Shouldn't it be `t1.e<>t2.e`?

Comment: In general, prefer `t1.e IN ('sa', 'mo')` rather than using `OR`. It's easier to read, and I think MySQL optimizes it better when there's an index on the column.

Comment: But first, **loose** the word `table` in: `select * from table t1`  ??

Comment: ```select t1.* from table t1 join table t2 on t1.a=t2.a and t1.e <> t2.e and t1.f <> t2.f``` ? Maybe additionally ```order by t1.a, t1.e```. https://dbfiddle.uk/iJ4bTjdH (thanks to @Luuk for a fiddle).

Comment: @Luuk Please Read, Write, Add, and Delete your question

Comment: @Error_2646: It's not my question...

Comment: @Luuk My dumb joke made more sense before you corrected rwad ;)

Comment: @Error_2646: No , because the SQL statement in the question is simply incorrect, and typing `rwad` in stead of `read` is just a typo.....

Comment: @Luuk No offense meant, it was clear that rwad was a typo. It was a joke about what rwad could stand for.

Comment: @Error_2646:L Sorry,  I am not an (native) English speaker, so I do not get that joke 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first identifying which values of `a` have 2 values for `f`, then only including rows with those values for `a`?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE e IN ('sa', 'mo')
AND a IN (
  SELECT a
  FROM t1
  WHERE e IN ('sa', 'mo')
  GROUP BY a
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT e) = 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT f) = 2
)
```

Comment: i think need updated  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 and  COUNT(DISTINCT f) > 1

Comment: Thanks - I modified the answer to enforce tighter criteria on the inner select: must have two rows per group, must have two different values of e per group, must have two different values of f per group